# Dynamic load balancing master-worker

Tags: c++, c, performance, parallel-processing, mpi

I have an array of index which I want each worker do something based on these indexes.
the size of the array might be more than the total number of ranks, so my first question is if there is another way except master-worker load balancing here? I want to have a balances system and also I want to assign each index to each ranks.

I was thinking about master-worker, and in this approach master rank (0) is giving each index to other ranks. but when I was running my code with 3 rank and 15 index my code is halting in while loop for sending the index 4. I was wondering If anybody can help me to find the problem

```
if(pCurrentID == 0) { // Master
   MPI_Status status;

   int nindices = 15;
   int mesg[1] = {0};
   int initial_id = 0;
   int recv_mesg[1] = {0};

  // -- send out initial ids to workers --//
   while (initial_id < size - 1) {
     if (initial_id < nindices) {
       MPI_Send(mesg, 1, MPI_INT, initial_id + 1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
       mesg[0] += 1;
       ++initial_id;
     }
   }

   //-- hand out id to workers dynamically --//
   while (mesg[0] != nindices) {
     MPI_Probe(MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
     int isource = status.MPI_SOURCE;
     MPI_Recv(recv_mesg, 1, MPI_INT, isource, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
     MPI_Send(mesg, 1, MPI_INT, isource, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
     mesg[0] += 1;
   }

   //-- hand out ending signals once done --//
   for (int rank = 1; rank < size; ++rank) {
     mesg[0] = -1;
     MPI_Send(mesg, 1, MPI_INT, rank, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
   }
 } else { 
   MPI_Status status;
   int id[1] = {0};
   // Get the surrounding fragment id
   MPI_Probe(MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
   int itag = status.MPI_TAG;
   MPI_Recv(id, 1, MPI_INT, 0, itag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
   
   int jfrag = id[0];
   if (jfrag < 0) break;
   // do something
   MPI_Send(id, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have an array of index which I want each worker do something based
> on these indexes. the size of the array might be more than the total
> number of ranks, so my first question is if there is another way
> except master-worker load balancing here? I want to have a balances
> system and also I want to assign each index to each ranks.

No, but if the work performed *per* array index takes roughly the same amount of time, you can simply *scatter* the array among the processes.

> I was thinking about master-worker, and in this approach master rank
> (0) is giving each index to other ranks. but when I was running my
> code with 3 rank and 15 index my code is halting in while loop for
> sending the index 4. I was wondering If anybody can help me to find
> the problem

As already pointed out in the comments, the problem is that you are missing (in the workers side) the loop of querying the master for work.

The load-balancer can be implemented as follows:

1. The master initial sends an iteration to the other workers;
2. Each worker waits for a message from the master;
3. Afterwards the master calls `MPI_Recv` from `MPI_ANY_SOURCE` and waits for another worker to request work;
4. After the worker finished working on its first iteration it sends its rank to the master, signaling the master to send a new iteration;
5. The master reads the rank sent by the worker in step 4., checks the array for a new index, and if there is still a valid index, send it to the worker. Otherwise, sends a special message signaling the worker that there is no more work to be performed. That message can be for instance `-1`;
6. When the worker receive the special message it stops working;
7. The master stops working when all the workers have receive the special message.

An example of such approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    MPI_Init(NULL,NULL); // Initialize the MPI environment
    int rank; 
    int size;
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);

    int work_is_done = -1;
    if(rank == 0){
       int max_index = 10; 
       int index_simulator = 0;
       // Send statically the first iterations
       for(int i = 1; i < size; i++){
           MPI_Send(&index_simulator, 1, MPI_INT, i, i, MPI_COMM_WORLD); 
           index_simulator++;
       }  
       int processes_finishing_work = 0;
     
       do{
          int process_that_wants_work = 0;
          MPI_Recv(&process_that_wants_work, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
          if(index_simulator < max_index){
             MPI_Send(&index_simulator, 1, MPI_INT, process_that_wants_work, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  
             index_simulator++;
          }
          else{ // send special message 
               MPI_Send(&work_is_done, 1, MPI_INT, process_that_wants_work, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
               processes_finishing_work++;
          }
       } while(processes_finishing_work < size - 1);
    }
    else{
        int index_to_work = 0;
        MPI_Recv(&index_to_work, 1, MPI_INT, 0, rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);    
        // Work with the iterations index_to_work
    
       do{
          MPI_Send(&rank, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
          MPI_Recv(&index_to_work, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
          if(index_to_work != work_is_done)
             // Work with the iterations index_to_work
       }while(index_to_work != work_is_done);
    }
    printf("Process {%d} -> I AM OUT\n", rank);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
 }
```

You can improve upon the aforementioned approach by reducing: 1) the number of messages sent and 2) the time waiting for them. For the former you can try to use a chunking strategy (*i.e.,* sending more than one index *per* MPI communication). For the latter you can try to play around with nonblocking MPI communications or have two threads *per* process one to receive/send the work another to actually perform the work. This multithreading approach would also allow the master process to actually work with the array indices, but it significantly complicates the approach.